# Add columns to Rails database in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add columns to my Rails app in production environment. Can't do it in development environment on my local machine because of installation problem on some bundles.

I ran this:

```
sudo ruby script/generate migration add_provider_to_spots provider:string provider_price:string provider_ref:string RAILS_ENV=production
```

But this error pops up:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:62:in `establish_connection': development database is not configured (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55:in `establish_connection'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:438:in `initialize_database'
.
.
.
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way

```
sudo RAILS_ENV=production ruby script/generate migration add_provider_to_spots provider:string provider_price:string provider_ref:string
```